# Video-popup loses background & breaks on scroll in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, video

I'm trying to create a website, on which there are multiple animations and multiple video's, when you click on an animation in the first video a popup comes up which works perfectly..

However when you click on an animation in the 2nd video the video-popup breaks, the buttons and the white-background of the video fall behind the full-screen-background-video, does anyone know why?

HTML for the popup-video:

Your browser doesn't support the video element. 
            

             

            
                Meer informatie
                Direct afsluiten

CSS for the pop-up video:

```
.popupInfo{
    display: none;
    padding: 15px;
    background:white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -20px 50px 0 -20px;
    z-index: 99999;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

#mask{
    display: none;
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 88888;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

HTML for second background-video which is under the first:

```
    <video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="background2">
        <source src="background/background2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </source>
        <source src="background/background2.ogv" type="video/ogg"> </source>
        <source src="background/background2.webm" type="video/webm"> </source>  
    </video>
```

CSS for the second background-video:

```
#background2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

CSS for both video's:

```
video { 
background:transparent url('../button/loading.gif') no-repeat 0 0; 
-webkit-background-size: 100px 100px; 
-moz-background-size: 100px 100px;
-o-background-size: 100px 100px;
background-size: 100px 100px;
background-position: center; 
}
```

CSS for the mask behind the video (which falls behind the background-video in Chrome)

```
#mask{
    display: none;
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 88888;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

jQuery for making the video-popup appear:

```
$("#vidKlik1").on('click', function(){
            bvideo2.pause();
            showPlaceHolder();
            showVID();
            changeVideoTo("fragmenten/real_schade");
            $("#video").load();
            $('#video').attr("autoplay", "autoplay");
        });
```

It only behaves like this in Google chrome.. in firefox it works completely normal, is there any work-around for this?

Edit:The buttons remain clickable and when you go to a different tab and come back to my website, it works and it appears as it should.